# How to arrange model items in a grid

Tags: model-view-controller, model, html-table, items

How do I organize my items in a table
so that my row has lets say 4 columns, in my

```
  foreach(var item in Model.Data)
  {
   <td>item.name</td>
  }
```

How do I have `item.name[i]`, `item.name[i+1]` so that I can fill out my column for the row?

Comment: Your question could be clearer. What is item.name - a string? Is item.name[i] a character? Did you mean item[i].name? What do you want in the columns - data from other rows, or other properties of the item at each iteration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear on exactly what you're asking or what version of MVC or View Engine, but the general pattern of a table displaying a collection of objects is

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>Hair Color</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
          <tr >
            <td><%= Html.Encode(item.Name) %></td>
            <td><%= Html.Encode(item.Description) %></td>
            <td><%= Html.Encode(item.HairColor) %></td>
          </tr>
        <% } %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this solution wouldnt work because the cell next to the first one is supposed to have the same kind of data, i.e. <td><%= Html.Encode(item.Name) %><%= Html.Encode(item.Description) %><%= Html.Encode(item.HairColor) %></td> and the next cell to have all these three properties as well... 

How I solved this:

I put them into Divs instead of a  table and used css float:right to  organize my divs into a grid